# Params for login not posting via REST using Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm trying to get my Demo Login Android Application to login via REST on my server with a login.php app which queries the local MySQL Database on the server.

When I run the REST Query from Insomnia, I specify the following JSON Array:

```
{
    "email": "cnorris@mail.com",
    "password": "hello"
}
```

And then on the response, I get the following:

```
{
  "login": [
    {
      "name": "Chuck",
      "email": "cnorris@mail.com",
      "id": "0"
    }
  ],
  "success": "1",
  "message": "success"
}
```

However in Android I'm getting a null response, which is the same response I would get if I didn't specify a JSON array. This is what my LoginActivity looks like:

```
package com.dafakamatt.androidregisterandlogin;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email, password;
    private Button btn_login;
    private TextView link_regist;
    private ProgressBar loading;
    private static String URL_LOGIN = "http://192.168.69.3/android_register_login/login.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        link_regist = findViewById(R.id.link_regist);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String mEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String mPass = password.getText().toString().trim();


                if (!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPass.isEmpty()) {
                    Login(mEmail, mPass);

                } else {
                    email.setError("Please insert email");
                    password.setError("Please insert password");
                }
            }
        });

        link_regist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    private void Login(final String email, final String password) {

        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                            if (success.equals("1")) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String name = object.getString("name").trim();
                                    String email = object.getString("email").trim();

                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                                            "Success Login. \nYour Name: "
                                                    + name + "\nYour Email: "
                                                    + email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                }
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error -" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email",email);
                params.put("password",password);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

My guess is that the overridden getParams() method isn't doing it's job because I've done something incorrectly.

My crash log is here when attempting to login:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
        at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
        at com.dafakamatt.androidregisterandlogin.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:83)
        at com.dafakamatt.androidregisterandlogin.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:79)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:78)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

This is the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dafakamatt.androidregisterandlogin">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeLogin"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeRegist">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the php code:

```
<?php

// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");



if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json);

    $email  = $obj->{'email'};
    $password = $obj->{'password'};

    require_once 'connect.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE email='" . $email . "' ";

    $response = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $result = array();
    $result['login'] = array();

    if ( mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1 ) {

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response);

        if ( password_verify($password, $row['password']) ) {

            $index['name'] = $row['name'];
            $index['email'] = $row['email'];
            $index['id'] = $row['id'];

            array_push($result['login'], $index);

            $result['success'] = "1";
            $result['message'] = "success";
            echo json_encode($result);

            mysqli_close($conn);

        } else {

            $result['success'] = "0";
            $result['message'] = "error";
            echo json_encode($result);

            mysqli_close($conn);

        }

    } 


}

?>
```

and the require_once connect.php:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "sql", "P@ssw0rd", "users");

?>
```

Any help is appreciated:

NB: I'm following this guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yS5n40h4Wlg&t=0s

Comment: The try/catch statement within the onResponse method fails with a JSON Exception:
```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
        at com.dafakamatt.androidregisterandlogin.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:83)
        at com.dafakamatt.androidregisterandlogin.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:79)
```

Comment: When debugging, the "response" variable is null also.

Comment: if response is null, the preceding code will fail, so better put an if condition to check whether it's null or not.

Comment: isn't that what the try/catch block for?

Comment: On both an emulator and a physical device.

Comment: make sure that IP of physical device is correct

Comment: It is correct. It's on the same network as the server.

Answer (score 1):

I want to tell you one thing about this `exception` :

> org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
>    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)

It means you are not getting any `JSON` response. You need to debug your code to find out why this is happening.

I think it has some backend problem.

**EDIT :**

```
    if ( password_verify($password, $row['password']) ) {

        $index['name'] = $row['name'];
        $index['email'] = $row['email'];
        $index['id'] = $row['id'];

        array_push($result['login'], $index);

        $result['success'] = "1";
        $result['message'] = "success";
        return json_encode($result);

        mysqli_close($conn);

    } else {

        $result['success'] = "0";
        $result['message'] = "error";
        return json_encode($result);

        mysqli_close($conn);

    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190550/discussion-on-answer-by-abhinav-gupta-params-for-login-not-posting-via-rest-usin). Please be sure to [edit] the answer to include all relevant information.

Comment: Hi Abinav, This PHP code works when using insomnia and specifying the parameters in the JSON body

Comment: I have changed this for android : return json_encode($result); in if/else condition @MatthewJones

Comment: Oh right, apologies I missed that. I updated the code to have the return statements in it, however the value of the response in Android is istill the same: "RESPONSE : "

Comment: @MatthewJones Sorry bro, I don't know that php much I gave my 100% to solve your issue but I can assure you in your android code there is no mistake in that please contact any of your friend who knows backend thing sorry bro. Happy coding.. :) if any query in android contact mail : abhinavguptabit@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If your finding that it's working withing a test client but not via your client(app) then check that the requested payload is the same. Generally there is some http headers difference that catches people out.